# make optional prop in interface on implementation not optional

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

assume we have an interface `IFieldConfig`

```
export interface IFieldInputConfig {
    type: 'string' | 'password';
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    default?: any;
}

export interface IFieldConfig extends IExtractConfig {
    id: string;
    form?: IFieldInputConfig;
}
```

and have an object that uses that interface

```
export const fieldCompany: IFieldConfig = {
    id: 'company',
    form: {
        type: 'string',
        default: 'Apple',
    },
}
```

when I want to consume this, TypeScript thinks `fieldCompany.form.default` could be undefined, even if it's very clear that it is defined. I understand, that after the declaration somehow the `form` prop *could* be deleted so TypeScript is not wrong.

How can I tell TypeScript this is sealed/wont be modified?

Obviously I could make more specific interfaces but I don't want to end up with one for every combination of optional props. I am sure there is an easier and more straightforward way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking I wouldn't annotate a variable with a type unless I *want* the compiler to "forget" the specifics of the value being assigned.  Only union-typed values will get narrowed on assignment, and `IFieldConfig` is not itself a union type. So when you assign a value to a variable of type `IFieldConfig`, the type of the variable is not narrowed via control flow analysis to anything more specific.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#16976](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16976) and [microsoft/TypeScript#27706](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27706) for more information.

My suggestion here (without more info to lead me to believe otherwise) is to leave off the annotation of `fieldCompany`, and use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to keep the inferred type as narrow as possible:

```
const fieldCompany = {
  id: 'company',
  form: {
    type: 'string',
    default: 'Apple',
  },
} as const;
```

You can tweak this if you want (e.g., maybe only the `type` filed of `form` should be `as const`), depending on which parts of the structure you intend to allow to change and which parts should stay narrow/fixed.

Since TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) and not nominal, this should not prevent you from using `fieldCompany` as an `IFieldConfig`:

```
function acceptIFieldConfig(c: IFieldConfig) { }
acceptIFieldConfig(fieldCompany); // okay
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FDCWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjaACAkgMVNANgCYbgAOArpAMID248oA5mgN7BpqQCeJ0AXGgHIAzpFgQGAtAB9BJREKEB3arAICA3GzQB6bWmhC8ESAFoCoIYgBGeaCfDQAHqaMO0AAS48hyMSVMGrpDa4NQmTiRGyKCmiOCcWgTQSGR4kAD8-HGcmgC+IMZwSKiYOPgENHSMLFqgBPwiYuAMmuzwKgC2maW4hMTkVLT0LcD5aCDItCJo9OU0HXLxaAC8Nex1-AKTC9kCADRa7bAd-Kzs7F58go3i+1rsSSlpmwCCJJHQd+y5B7lo8mhJuARJpgPAyOBkJBQLR-shUP5sL0KkNGAAKZD8JFzVEMACULDQ+RQCMg2MIlWGaNmFOoO3iePUOj01AA1ohOEA)

Comment: *"Since TypeScript's type system is structural and not nominal..."* <== foundational concept, wonderfully concisely put!

Answer (score 3):

I may be being a bit simplistic, but one solution that jumps out is just not to say it's an `IFieldConfig` at all:

```
export const fieldCompany = {
  id: 'company',
  form: {
    type: 'string' as const, // <=== Note
    default: 'Apple',
  },
};
```

Now, `fieldCompany.form.default` is type `string`, not `string | undefined`. You need the `as const` on `type: 'string'` because otherwise it will be inferred as `string`, not `'string' | 'password'`.

The object is still assignment compatible with `IFieldConfig`; this works:

```
const x: IFieldConfig = fieldCompany;
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQDEFgAbAE3yTAFcYBhCJdBAczgG8AoOXuGAJ5hgALjgByAM4woyVuLgAfCWEyTJAd2jlxAbh58A9IbjBJpZDAC05BJMwAjUsCtJQ1i27gABQcMnYsmDWZp4whkgQVqBgFtgI1phIAga85MBYNKQwAPxiSQL6AL5cXDHQ8JZoWLgExGTkjMxscIYAVKYgqEjkkgQAol1QOAxMLOxtJtx8iORi0rJIrLrkBujQALZ5dSQUVLSjzctcJWXgFXDYTNJwLA2MG6rJcAC8nAYIcxJXjwXiADRrTZiaZ8PyiCQLOQKNSXa4wQEzdKZbJicQAQTAsWAAIMRUBRX0XDuFAeTwEADp1lANhTkZgsjBSuVYHCkDcQGIiLtGmMWm8Sbzfsl9EA)

Comment: thank you for the reply. the `as const` trick is interesting and seems to work in the playground. In my project its (string|undefined) again even though the configs seem to be identical

Comment: @japrescott - Huh. Did you try [jcalz's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61505481/157247)? It's similar but slightly different. He's much, much more knowledgeable about TypeScript than I am.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on playground and indeed it complains about `undefined` possibility.

But to your rescue you have some workarounds!

[Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)

```js
fieldCompany.form!.default
```

You can also **disable strict null checks**

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullchecks": false
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. Turning off `strictNullchecks` is not a possibility. The non-null assertion is interesting but doesn't solve the underlying problem

Answer (score 0):

You may define a generic DeepRequired to get something like this:

```
  interface IExtractConfig{}

  export interface IFieldInputConfig<L extends any = any> {
    type: 'string' | 'password';
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    default?: L;
  }

  export interface IFieldConfig<L extends any = any> extends IExtractConfig {
    id: string;
    form?: IFieldInputConfig<L>;
  }

  type DeepRequired<T> = Required<{
    [K in keyof T]: Required<DeepRequired<T[K]>>
  }>

  export const fieldCompany: DeepRequired<IFieldConfig<string>> = {
    id: 'company',
    form: {
        type: 'string',
        default: 'Apple',
    },
  }
```

Typescript would not be happy with default:any field. therefore I change it to generic parameter.

Now you have it `fieldCompany.form.default` has `"string"`

```
  function user(fc:DeepRequired<IFieldConfig<string>>){
    //here         fc.form.default assumed to be "string" and not "string" | "undefined" 
  }
```

Some time you have to have the base interface with optional properties. But from my experience using all properties as mandatory is better. Latter you can use Partial and Pick to cut the original shape in pieces.